# How to Asynchronously wait in Angular 5 +?

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core-2.0

TypeScript:

```
getSocialDataTwitter(searchQuery) {
  this.fetchLists(searchQuery);
  const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('content-type', 'application/json');
  return this.http.post<RightOperatorPaneltwitter>(this.baseUrl + 'api/OperationData/GetAllTweetsByNamePost', this.lists, { headers }).subscribe(result => {
    this.tweets = result;
  }, error => console.error(error));
}

fetchLists(searchQuery) {
  this.listService.getLists()
    .subscribe((data: List[]) => {
      data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.name === searchQuery) {

          this.lists = d;
        }
      })
    });
}
```

I am new to Angular 5 + .Netcore 2.0. I would like to  use `fetchLists` to get data from my mongo db using node.js. and send it to my api controller. I am getting the data from the database successfully. After the first click the object to my controller is in the default initialised state and after the second click the controller gets the data that I am expecting. Is there a way to wait for the `fetchLists` to finish process then execute the post requested to the api controller. I would like the user to see the data after once click.

Am I wrong to think that using the `.subcribe` is asynchronous?

Comment: Depending on how your `getLists` is implemented, you might not have any asynchronous actions at all... `.subscribe` is used to get data from a observable, which might be asynchronous, but it's not a guarantee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to is to chain your both calls using merge map. I modified your example to show what to do.

First of all, your `fetchLists` method should not subscribe to the list service but rather only convert the data and return the resulting observable. Then in your `getSocialDataTwitter` method you will call `fetchLists` and use mergeMap to chain your second http call.

```
fetchLists(searchQuery) {
    // Make note how we map the result and then return the observable 
    // without subscribing.
    return this.listService.getLists()
    .pipe(
        map((data: List[]) => data.find(d => d.name === searchQuery))
    )
}

getSocialDataTwitter(searchQuery) {
    // As the headers and url will not change, we can define them here
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('content-type', 'application/json');
    const url = this.baseUrl + 'api/OperationData/GetAllTweetsByNamePost';

    // Here we call our initial method, but instead of subscribing directly
    // we use mergeMap to chain our observables
    this.fetchLists(searchQuery)
        .pipe(
            // Lists is the result we created with the map in fetchLists.
            mergeMap(lists => this.http.post<RightOperatorPaneltwitter>(url, lists, { headers }))
        )
        // Only after we subscribe here, the list service is called.
        .subscribe(result => this.tweets = result);
}
```

Comment: I have import `import { mergeMap, map, find } from 'rxjs/operators';` and I am getting this error message on .find `(TS) Property 'find' does not exist on type 'List[]'` But my project works as I expected it to. Is it a bug?

Comment: You don't need to import find from rxjs, as find should be a native method on the array object. I think you might fix the error by chaning `(data: List[])` to `any[]`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you could simply execute the post request here:

```
fetchLists(searchQuery) {
  this.listService.getLists()
    .subscribe((data: List[]) => {
      data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.name === searchQuery) {

          this.lists = d;
        }
      })

      // EXECUTE HERE
    });
}
```

This way, you'd fetch your list, process it and then execute your post. Using observables is called reactive programming. As stated [here](https://dzone.com/articles/5-things-to-know-about-reactive-programming),

> Reactive Programming Is Programming With Asynchronous Data Streams

Comment: While you are correct that this will work, you should not nest subscribe calls with rxjs. There might be some cases where it makes sense, usually it is a sign that you did not make full use of the rxjs streams. You can achieve a cleaner, more flexibel result if you try to make use of the streams and operators.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood your point your problem is that **this.fetchLists(searchQuery)** is executed but before the list is filled in the subscribe- method the API- Post is done.

I think you can fix that like this with the ES2017 async/await feature:

```
async getSocialDataTwitter(searchQuery) {
  await this.fetchLists(searchQuery);
  const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('content-type', 'application/json');
  return this.http.post<RightOperatorPaneltwitter>(this.baseUrl + 'api/OperationData/GetAllTweetsByNamePost', this.lists, { headers }).subscribe(result => 
  {
   this.tweets = result;
  }, error => console.error(error));
}
```

Comment: Before posting this question my first though was to try the async/ await keyword. Because I wanted to do async all the way. I first wanted to start with making `fetchLists` asynchronous too but then I got this error `(TS) An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor. Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your --lib option. I have try your answer and it works as expected. My question is how am I aloud to await `fetchLists` and (it is not async ?)

Comment: The **async** means that a function always returns a promise. If it has a non-promise, then JS automatically wraps it with a resolved promise. And finally the **await** makes JS wait until the Promise had resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You can create additional method which will call the fetchlist and returns the observable result, then we can call the getSocialDataTwitter() method.

```
fetchLists(searchQuery) {
  return this.listService.getLists()
    .subscribe((data: List[]) => {
      data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.name === searchQuery) {
          this.lists = d;
        }
      });
      return Observable.of(this.lists);
    });
}

getData(){
    return this.fetchLists(searchQuery).pipe(
       this.fetchLists(),
       switchMap((result)=>{
          return this.getSocialDataTwitter();
       })
    )
}
```

Comment: `return of(this.lists);` is the of keyword a typo because I am getting (TS) Cannot find name 'of' when I remove of I have no errors.

Comment: You need to import RXJS of operator. import {of} from 'rxjs';

Comment: @ArgonitasI answer works for me but I am very curious so I wanted to try all the answer that are provided. I am getting (TS)Module {{APathOnMyPC}} has no exported member 'of' when I do the import. I am using ` "@angular/core": "^5.2.0"` with ` "rxjs": "^5.5.6"`

Comment: use this.import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';